# Suspend Problem (?)

Tags: gtk

does anyone experience UI problems when waking up from suspend? What I meant is not the black screen problem, it seems like the GTK theme is broken when waking up and this happened randomly. For example, when i opened the settings, all of the texts are missing.

My System is using Intel 4600 + Nvidia 960M (Nvidia disabled via prime)
GTK theme is arc

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem up until today, when i installed the latest OS update (the one with the new AppCenter), i think it had an update to the nvidia driver.
Afterwards the behavior stabilized and everything is working now.
Try to run the updates and come back if the issue wasn't solved.

I run dell XPS with nvidia 1050 + intel HD

Comment: hmm okay then, lemme see later if this new driver solved this problem or not haha. I was thinking the arc theme was the one that broke the gtk, but idk for sure. Thanks btw !